# Get item count from pgs subtitles with python

Tags: python, subtitle

I need count how many items (lines) have a subtitle file in PGS format. I don't need convert it to SRT or make any OCR operation.

Is there any way to get the number of items in a PGS file using python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to find the number of lines, then try this:

```
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('myfile.pgs'))
```